# Flutter Sensors_Plus package not working correctly on certain devices

Tags: flutter, gyroscope

I am trying to create a goniometer, a device used to measure angular measurements in both the vertical and horizontal planes. I am developing the application in Flutter, and using the Sensors_Plus package to obtain sensor data.

The issue I am running into relates to horizontal plane measurements (i.e. when the device is flat and tilted left or right). I am using the gyroscope measurements (changes in angular velocity), and integrating over them with regards to changes in time to calculate the total angle.

On most devices, this approach works adequately, however on a select few the measurements are buggy, or fail to even register. Interestingly, the issue is only occurring on the Flutter application. Users have tested the same type of measurement on native Android apps and are able to measure the angles successfully.

I am hoping that someone else has tried to accomplish something similar, or has some advice on how to deal with it.

Thanks!